# MVC3 missing in Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I had VS 2010 ultimate installed. It had no MVC3. I installed SP1, which should have installed  updates as well as MVC3 too - right ?

But after installation, I still don't have MVC3 option in new project window.
What's wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MVC3 is an optional download: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 3):

As JK says, MVC3 is an additional download.

Also (one thing that had me scratching me head for a while) when it is installed, then make sure that .net4 is selected for framework - MVC3 won't show up if the current framework is earlier.

Comment: Yeah, I read it on another question here. Thanks for replying

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment to the answer and not another answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can get source from this link
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=1491